# Magento Module AJAX action in MultishippingController returns 302 when not logged in

Tags: ajax, register

I am writing a custom module to add some functionality to the Multishipping Register page. I've extended the Mage_Checkout_MultishippingController class with an action

public function verifyRegisterAction()
{
     Mage::log("testing..",null,"verifyRegisterAction.log");
     // some stuff...

```
 $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
 $this->getResponse()->setBody(json_encode($data));
```

}

I am able to call this action successfully by browsing to /checkout/multishipping/verifyRegister when I am logged in. I can see the log gets written to and see the json response. However, if I am not logged in then I get a HTTP 302 response and nothing is written to the log.

The registerAction() is obviously available since it renders the register page itself. What do I need to do to make this action available when not authenticated? What steps can I take to debug what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774900/magento-extending-customer-account-controller-to-add-actions-to-the-forgot-pass

I had to update the preDispatch function and manually set the response to HTTP 200.